# Force container with inline css to take height of child

Tags: html, css

Here is my html:

```
<div class="content">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div style="height: 1px !important;" class="item">
        <div style="height: 100px;" class="item-child"></div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

In this scenerio, `.item` has an inline height set to 1px. `.item-child` has an inline height set to 100px. Is there a way to basically overrule the `.item` inline style and have that div take the same height as the `.item-child` div?

These values are applied programmatically so I can't just edit the HTML. Also, the `.item-child` div can be a variety of different heights.

Finally, I would prefer a css solution instead of js but haven't been able to come up with css that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to simply get rid of the `item` element using [`display: contents;`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid red; /*You won't see the border because the element is removed*/
  display: contents;
}

.item-child {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>text here</p>
  <p>text here</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>and text here</p>
  <div style="height: 1px !important;" class="item">
    <div style="height: 100px;" class="item-child"></div>
  </div>
  <p>also text here</p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oooooh, and Temani coming off the top rope once again! Only issue would be with IE/Edge/Safari

Comment: @ChrisW. who care about IE and Edge ;) it should work on Safari but it's buggy. It should only be a matter of time to have better support. By the way, I don't see any other CSS only solution (tried with min-height and it wasn't working)

Comment: Haha "who care about IE and Edge" -- when this day comes universally to all enterprise software devs the heavens will open and free beer will flow for days...although to be fair, the new Edge/Chromium conversion seems to be going pretty darn well, now if we can just convince Satya to bury IE life would be so much easier :D

Comment: Edge does handle most things fairly well. Still not perfect but we've come a long way from IE6 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I mean, it's doing what you would expect box model to do. I can't think of any other way than to pro grammatically change the style css of the parent since css doesn't do much for reverse/previous elements since a DOM cascades top -> down. However a simple poc;

```js
changeParentHeight = (parentClass, childClass) => {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.'+parentClass),
        child = document.querySelector('.'+childClass);
  parent.style.height = child.style.height;
}
```

```css
div div {
  border: red 2px dashed;
}

div div div {
  border: green 2px dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div style="height: 1px !important;" class="item">
        <div style="height: 100px;" class="item-child"></div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<button type="button" onclick="changeParentHeight('item', 'item-child')">Change Height</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a much more simple approach that requires no javascript for this.

```
.content div[style] {
   height: 100px !important;
}
```

Are the values static so you know what to target in advance or are they dynamic?

Comment: You might want to test this, the specificity selector hack won't work with that selector ref and arguably it even did it leaves a lot of room for undesired results since it sounds like he's probably a lot of programmatic inline styles on various elements going on in the real world example.

Comment: I appreciate the candor, but add `overflow: hidden` to the `.item` class div. Notice this fixes nothing, you're just seeing visible overflow with your "very basic" fix and the confidence is illusion. Sorry, we've all been there though so no worries ;)

Comment: All good, I'm not easily offended. I've been at this a long time, if I took constructive criticism poorly I'd be in the wrong job.  You have a valid point!